# Differences between "technic" and "technique"

Tags: word-choice, differences

Are those synonyms? Is one more acceptable in a certain dialect than the other?

I checked their definition on The Free Dictionary but it's still not clear to me.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised to find someone using "technic" as an adjective, intending to mean "technical" or some such.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Technique* is the standard spelling.  *Technic* is a variant, for example used for trade names such as by [Lego](http://technic.lego.com/) and [Panasonic](http://www.panasonic.com/consumer_electronics/technics_dj/flash.asp) and may sometimes be pronounced with a shorter unstressed *i*.

Comment: So it's only used for commercial needs, like 'Mortal Kombat', 'Xtremer' or 'Snoop Dogg'?

Comment: BTW, see [Sensational spelling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensational_spelling) and [Satiric misspelling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satiric_misspelling) on Wikipedia.

Comment: @HuBeZa: Apparently Hemmingway used it once, so I would hesitate to say it cannot be used in normal speech.  I could imagine a speculative fiction novel where members of the engineering class are called *Technics*.  It is the stem of words like *pyrotechnics* and *polytechnic*.  But I think it should be avoided in normal use when *techniques* can be used instead.

Answer (score 15):

*Technique* and *technic* are synonyms ([as shown on Merriam-Webster's entry for technic](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/technic)).

Note that *technique* is by far more used than *technic*. Compare the number of matches found for the two words:

```
Corpus of Contemporary American English (COCA)
technique = 13383
technic = 18

British National Corpus (BNC)
technique = 4601
technic = 9

Google
technique = 271M
technic = 14M
```

According to the data from [Google Ngram Viewer](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=technique%2Ctechnic&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3) shown below, *technic* was more commonly used between 1900 and 1970 than it is today. As for *technique*, usage increased since the early 1900's until now, except in the past two decades or so, in which for some reason (?) the number of occurrences decreased in comparison to other general words.

[image]

Comment: That's a double top: Sell!!

Comment: "Technique"'s decline could be the rise of "Methodology": http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=technic%2C+methodology&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3. On a personal note, I hate the word "methodology".

Comment: @tenfour: interesting theory, although methodology is the study of methods\techniques, and not the technique itself.

Comment: The reason I hate "methodology" is because it's so commonly used in place of the simpler, "method". My theory is a snide nod in that direction :P

Comment: This says nothing about the meaning of the uses, so I hate to say this but the graphs are eye candy that don't really explain the situation.

Comment: @Robusto In this case it's helpful to understand that the terminology has changed over time.  In other words, the graphs demonstrate "common usage" and as such apply where the words are essentially synonyms.

Comment: Would be nice if the graphs were to scale with each other, though.  First glance suggests that they have similar peaks, but the reality is that the technic graph fits completely under the technique graph - in other words technic was never as widely used as technique.

Comment: @Adam Davis, agreed. I just updated the post with a combined chart to show the scale.